# How to obtain ports that a process in listening on?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, port

How do I get the ports that a process is listening on using python? The pid of the process is known.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process(2549)
>>> p.name()
'proftpd: (accepting connections)'
>>> p.connections()
[connection(fd=1, family=10, type=1, local_address=('::', 21), remote_address=(), status='LISTEN')]
```

...To filter for listening sockets:

```
>>> [x for x in p.get_connections() if x.status == psutil.CONN_LISTEN]
[connection(fd=1, family=10, type=1, local_address=('::', 21), remote_address=(), status='LISTEN')]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. psutil is a good module. But the only problem is that using the module need it to be installed first. And installing psutil needs gcc and python headers to be installed. So the project using psutil would be hard to install.

Comment: psutil needs gcc because it contains C code which needs to be compiled. I wouldn't go as far as saying it's that hard to install, especially on Linux. On Ubuntu, for example, you simply need to "apt-get install python-dev" and "pip install psutil" and you're done.

Answer (score 25):

There are two parts to my answer:

**1. Getting the information in the shell**

For the first part, `netstat` would work, but I prefer using `lsof`, since it can be used to extract a more informative and concise list. The exact options to use may vary based on your OS, kernel and compilation options, but I believe you want something like this:

```
lsof -a -p23819 -i4
```

Where `23819` is the PID you are selecting for, and `i4` denotes all IPv4 sockets (though you might want `i6` for IPv6, as the case may be). From there, you can pipe through grep to select only listening sockets.

```
lsof -a -p23819 -i4 | grep LISTEN
```

(In `lsof` version 4.82, you can additionally use the `-sTCP:LISTEN` flag instead of `grep` to select listening sockets, though this option doesn't seem to be available back in version 4.78)

**2. Calling `lsof` from Python**

You should be able to call `lsof` and read the output, from Python, using the `subprocess` module, like so:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(['lsof', '-a', '-p23819', '-i4'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "LISTEN"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this works well, thanks. small 2024 update (at least for debian recent flavors) :  
`lsof -Pa -p23819 -i4 -sTCP:LISTEN` the P switch will show the port as digits (and not http-alt if 23819 port is not 80)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to parse the output of a program like netstat or lsof, you can grovel through the /proc filesystem and try to find documentation on the files within.  `/proc/<pid>/net/tcp` might be especially interesting to you.  Of course, the format of those files might change between kernel releases, so parsing command output is generally considered more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netstat -lnp`, last column will contain pid and process name. In Python you can parse output of this command.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that wasn't mentioned. Most port applications in python take a command line argument. You can parse /proc/pid/cmdline and parse out the port number. This avoids the large overhead of using ss or netstat on servers with a ton of connections.