# Packet spoofing using python

Tags: python, windows, network-programming

I'm trying to write a proof of concept code, which will automatically spoof packets to a thick-client application.

I've chosen python as the language of choice. I have found resources to help me monitor for packets using scapy or other similar libraries.

How do I go about spoofing the packet.

Eg. Scenario :
Client C, Server S

C sends get request R(HTTP) to S
Proxy_python intercepts request R
Proxy_python crafts a HTTP response (r) 
Proxy_python sends r to C

Essentially a MiTm on C. Is this possible. One condition to note is that, the proxy i'm writing should not need any configuration to get redirected to. It should ubiquotously listen for all packets.

Which makes me ask me another question : Can I make the python proxy listen to a particular PID ?

Comment: So, what's your question, exactly?

Comment: I'm asking whether, it is indeed possible to do this, ie. Get packets from only a particular PID. In this case C's PID

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least to answer the question regarding whether you can tie a PID to the packets being sent, this is not something that is explicitly included within the packet data.  However, you can determine which port the process is sending traffic on and associate packets on that port to the process.  I would reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987168/how-to-obtain-ports-that-a-process-in-listening-on) for some information on how to get that port info.  Hope this helps a little, not sure exactly what else you are looking for at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work. That will help me filter packets,essentially. The reason why I'm trying to write my own script is because, proxies such as Fiddler, do not recognize http packets sent from thick client applications, since the packets are not routed through them.