# Identify listening ports of specific process ID with python

Tags: python, subprocess, port, popen

I want to identify the listening port of a specific process ID (on a *nix system) with python.

In bash I would: `netstat -tulpn | grep 12345 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2`, where `12345` is the process of interest.

I took the command and tried to use it with `check_output`:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> (check_output("netstat -tulpn | grep 12345 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2", shell=True)).decode("utf-8").rstrip()
'54321'
```

That's a pretty static and really not pythonic.

Is there a proper way to identify the listening port of a given process with Python?

I `Popen` the process of interest in the very same script, if that makes a difference.

*edit:* If possible, I'd like to avoid importing third-party functions like `psutil`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain ports that a process in listening on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987168/how-to-obtain-ports-that-a-process-in-listening-on). Check the `psutil` answer.

Comment: I'd rather not use any third party tools. I'll update the OP @AshishNitinPatil