# Getting all PID Id's and Ports being Listened to with Python

Tags: python, port, pid

I'm currently learning some python and I was just wondering what is the best way to get a list of all the PID Id's of say Firefox and then displaying all the port numbers it is listening to. I am trying to replicate the image below and yet I can't seem to figure it out. Sorry in advance but I currently do not have any code atm as I've been testing and trying code that I have googled and found to no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the package [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`pip install psutil`

Now for your desired output, iterate over all process and find the one with 'firefox' in its name

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        processName = proc.name()
        if "firefox" in processName:
            processID = proc.pid
            print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
```

Comment: A detailed guide of psutil is here : https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/

Comment: Thank you for this, it actually helps a lot

Just in case Im missing something from the link, after getting the PIDS, hows the best way of taking them and finding the ports/IP Addresses that it is listening on?

Comment: Check this link https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#network and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987168/how-to-obtain-ports-that-a-process-in-listening-on/6244347

Comment: Is not a answer. Your code no output for ports of  process.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a skeleton for what you're looking for:

```
import psutil

pids = []
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try: 
        name = p.name()
        if "firefox" in name.lower():
            pids.append(p.pid)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass

connections = psutil.net_connections()

for con in connections: 
  if con.pid in pids:
    print (con)
```